# angular2 rc6 event emitter - parent child interaction example

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am looking for an example that explains how parent child interaction using event emission works in angular2-rc6 version (that no longer makes use of directives). Most of the links available online seem to have the directives tag functional (older version of angular2).

Answer (score 1):

See this link on [COMPONENT INTERACTION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)

**VoterComponent**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="voted">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="voted">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  voted = false;
  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.onVoted.emit(agreed);
    this.voted = true;
  }
}
```

**VoteTakerComponent**

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'vote-taker',
  template: `
    <h2>Should mankind colonize the Universe?</h2>
    <h3>Agree: {{agreed}}, Disagree: {{disagreed}}</h3>
    <my-voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
      [name]="voter"
      (onVoted)="onVoted($event)">
    </my-voter>
  `
})
export class VoteTakerComponent {
  agreed = 0;
  disagreed = 0;
  voters = ['Mr. IQ', 'Ms. Universe', 'Bombasto'];
  onVoted(agreed: boolean) {
    agreed ? this.agreed++ : this.disagreed++;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!